# How can I determine the vulnerability for a sub domain takeover attack?

Tags: dns, known-vulnerabilities, reconnaissance, sub-domain

I have found research efforts on explaining how sub domain takeovers can take place authored by a gentleman named "Patrik Hudák". Through his site's blogs he illustrates and conveys an understanding of the phenomenon:

https://0xpatrik.com/subdomain-takeover/

He has also crafted a Master's thesis on the subject matter:

https://is.muni.cz/th/byrdn/Thesis.pdf

I would like to find specific fields of interest using some advised tools such as dig, whois and curl to distinguish if a subdomain is vulnerable or not.

Comment: This question is also posted in quora:

https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-I-determine-the-presence-of-a-vulnerability-for-a-sub-domain-takeover-attack

Comment: Reaching out via twitter too:

https://twitter.com/azaam90/status/1074749419705196544

Comment: The details in the blog post make it clear: it's about the expiry of the domain.

Comment: The author also explained his process: https://0xpatrik.com/subdomain-takeover-candidates/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually know Patrik personally and will definitely ping him concerning your request.

I have published numerous technical write-ups on subdomain takeovers that include identifying vulnerable hosts using common commands and libraries that may be of interest to you. The best starting point is probably "[A guide to subdomain takeovers](https://www.hackerone.com/blog/Guide-Subdomain-Takeovers)".

### Setup and workflow

If you want a really basic setup, I would advise to use a combination of a subdomain enumeration tool to retrieve a list of subdomains for your target, [`meg`](https://github.com/tomnomnom/meg) for sending requests and storing the responses in a local folder, and then grepping for fingerprints listed in "[Can I takeover XYZ?](https://github.com/EdOverflow/can-i-take-over-xyz)" (most subdomain takeover related tools rely on this project for identifying vulnerable hosts) in the folder where meg stored the responses.

A basic workflow using the tools listed above would look roughly as follows.

1) Enumerate subdomains using a tool such as [subfinder](https://github.com/subfinder/subfinder) (the process that these tools use is described in detail in the HackerOne write-up linked above);

```
$ subfinder -d example.com -o output-tmp.txt
```

2) Ensure that all hosts are prefixed with `http://` so that they can be run through `meg`. You could also use [`httprobe`](https://github.com/tomnomnom/httprobe), which is a slower process but might yield better results;

```
$ sed 's#^#http://#g' output-tmp.txt > output.txt
```

3) Run `meg` to fetch the index pages of all the enumerated subdomains;

```
$ meg -L -c 200 / output.txt responses
```

4) Grep through the responses for fingerprints associated with vulnerable subdomains.

```
$ grep -Hnri "There isn't a Github Pages site here." responses
```

### Practice

In my opinion, the simplest way to learn about subdomain takeovers is to point a subdomain of yours to GitHub pages and to follow the steps above to claim it. This should give you a feel for the entire workflow and possibly give you a better idea of the security implications.

### Further reading

"[DNS hijacking using cloud providers – No verification needed](https://www.slideshare.net/fransrosen/dns-hijacking-using-cloud-providers-no-verification-needed-76812183)" by Frans Rosén covers a lot of the steps described in the previous section. He also goes into detail about how he identifies vulnerable subdomains and lists a couple of tricks to make your workflow more efficient.